# What exactly does "The numbers are in" mean?

Tags: meaning

> The numbers are in

Below are what I think the expression might mean. Are they correct?

> *"The processed statistical datas are now available"*
>
> *"The numbers are increasing"*?

[Usage Example](https://youtu.be/wJUXLqNHCaI?t=9s) that I found.

Comment: Please google *meaning of the numbers are in* and tell us what you find.

Comment: I can't find it; I did try searching it.

Comment: Ok, so long as you searched first, I'm satisfied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means the former: the numbers (whatever numerical data is under discussion) are now available.

For reference, I tried a couple of variants of the search suggested by Dan Bron, and I can't find the answer there either (when I quote the phrase, this question is now the first hit).

Answer (score 3):

The first one, "The processed data are now available" is the meaning you're looking for.

If it were "the numbers are increasing" the term would be

> The numbers are up.